# How to create state for muliplte input fields with duplication in React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I'm having difficulty in updating state with a React/Redux setup while trying to update the state of muliple input fields in a form. I'm getting the state updated, but there is an index for every keyup.

How can I update the state to only include the updated items in state?

expected

```
userGenerated:
Array(4)
0:{yourName: "fg"}
1:{yourStory: "gd"}
```

actual

```
userGenerated:
Array(4)
0:{yourName: "f"}
1:{yourName: "fg"}
2:{yourStory: "g"}
3:{yourStory: "gd"}
```

reducer

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "USER_GEN_INPUT":
      let { input, name } = action.payload;

      let newState = state;

      let userGenerated = {
        [name]: input
      };

      return [...newState, userGenerated];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

action

```
export function handleUserGenInput(input, name) {
  return {
    type: actions.USER_GEN_INPUT,
    payload: {
      input,
      name
    }
  };
}
```

component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { handleUserGenInput } from "../actions";

/**
 * Form to handle User Generated Content
 * And post to the back end of WP - CRV
 */
class UserGenerated extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onHandleChange = this.onHandleChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  // Handle submitting the form to the backend
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  // Dispatch the action to the Redux store whenever a change event happens
  onHandleChange(e) {
    /**
     * @param value of input field
     * @param name of input field
     */
    this.props.handleUserGenInput(e.target.value, e.target.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.props.value}
            name="yourName"
            onChange={this.onHandleChange}
          />
          <textarea name="yourStory" onChange={this.onHandleChange} />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { userGenerated: state.userGenerated };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  handleUserGenInput
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserGenerated);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem is in your reducer:

```
return [...newState, userGenerated];
```

This is adding the entries to an array, so it just keeps getting bigger.
Instead try:

```
return {...newState, userGenerated};
```

It wont return an array, but I don't think an array is what you want.  This way you'll get:

```
{
    yourName: "fg",
    yourStory: "gd"
}
```

Comment: Oh geez. Thanks so much. I thought it needed to be an array because of the last project I was working on